# Pass a string to ASyncTask when NDEF_DISCOVERED

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest, nfc

I am working in NFC tag. My task is that when a NFC is scanned, I must read the NFC information and send it to `ASyncTask`. In `ASyncTask`, I will used the `HttpClient` to send that information to server. I read NFC information successfully. I searched and found my solution. I just used the simplest solution such as below.  That code works well. The `ASyncTask` is initialized in `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`, hence, when tag is scanned,  `ASyncTask` will be created and call the request to server. My problem is that `ASyncTask` created many times (whenever tag is scanned). Do we have any way to create `ASyncTask` just one time in `onCreate`, and we will pass a string to the `ASyncTask` when tag is scan?

```
    /////Read NFC Information///////////////
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            //Read NFC tag succesfull
            String NFC_information=100;
            new AsyncCallWS().execute("101");            
        }
    }
    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url="server_link"+params[0];
            try {               
                String content_feedback=getStringContent(url);

            } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }
    }
    public static String getStringContent(String uri) throws Exception {
    {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(uri));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            InputStream ips  = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ips,"UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String s;
            while(true )
            {
                s = buf.readLine();
                if(s==null || s.length()==0)
                    break;
                sb.append(s);

            }
            buf.close();
            ips.close();
            return sb.toString();

            } 
        finally { }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with this? your code is fine.

Comment: May be you need to create AsyncCallWS Object once in onCreate() and you need to call execute() using existing AsyncCallWS  object, Which was created in onCreate().

Comment: @DegenSharew: You can see that AsyncCallWS is created many time by new AsyncCallWS().execute("101");, hence, whenever tag is scaned, a  new AsyncCallWS() is called. I think that it is not necessary

Comment: I see that but it is fine.

Comment: Yes you are creating a new AsyncTask on each new Intent received,You could probably create it once during initalization of the Object and be calling the execute method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ...
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                //consider single message is there hence loop will iterate only once
                new MyAsync().execute(msgs[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    //process the msgs array
}

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Because after calling `onNewIntent`, `onResume` gets called.

Comment: Yes you can. Because the thing you want goes from here only do don't need redundancy